# Bind a Boolean variable inside an ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript, boolean, arraycollection

```
[Bindable]
public var isToggled:Boolean = true;

public var menuData:Array = [
    {label: "Sample", type: "check", toggled: {isToggled}}
];
```

I'm trying to bind the isToggled variable to the toggled property but I'm getting this error: 1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before dot. Maybe because it is treating {isToggled} as another object. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have advantages of declarative data binding within ActionScript code. It is allowed only within MXML tags. But you can declare your `Array` or `ArrayCollection` with MXML:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:ArrayCollection id="myCollection">
        <s:source>
            <fx:Array>
                <fx:Object label="Sample" type="check" toggled="{isToggled}" />
            </fx:Array>
        </s:source>
    </s:ArrayCollection>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had that before I started converting my MXML code to AS3. I really need to use an AS3 collection as a dataProvider.

Comment: In your case you should create `isToggled` as `get` and `set` accessor method (see more details [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f36.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcb)) and perform changes of data provider within setter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bindings ('{}') outside of mxml unless you use BindingUtils.  However, I wouldn't recommend that either because now you're copying your data.

Why do you need 2 boolean values? You already have the data just bind it using the menuData property.

Comment: I'm bulding a MenuBar using the MVC pattern. On the controller, I'm feeding the dataProvider property using an ArrayCollection. Those boolean properties represent values that can change when the user clicks on the menu or when the user uses a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You still haven't answered why you need to bind a property within the array to its own property instead of accessing the variable within the array directly...

Comment: When the user uses a keyboard shortcut that variable is changed and the toggled property in the menu changes too. But I'm being stupid. I'm going to change my approach to this problem. Thanks.